# Build error: java.io.FileNotFoundException After Android Studio2.2.1

Tags: android-studio, filenotfoundexception

Error:Execution failed for task ':library:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources'.

> Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Project\library\build\intermediates\res\merged\androidTest\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000.png (请求的操作无法在使用用户映射区域打开的文件上执行。)

Answer (score 0):

Update gradle version and build success.